# Updating viewmodel from worker thread throws cross thread issue

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, task, worker-thread

Recently, I've been testing with binding of type which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and updating property from worker thread throwing cross thread issue.

Here is sample code :

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (_name != value)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {

            PropertyChangedEventHandler hanlder = PropertyChanged;
           if(hanlder != null)
                hanlder(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        }
    }
```

above viewmodel has been bind with label text in windows form and updating label value from worker thread.

Updating label1 text from worker thread causes cross thread issue :

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private MyViewModel _myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Btn1.Click += Btn1_Click;
        label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", _myViewModel, "Name");

    }

    private void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            _myViewModel.Name = "Updating from worker thread!"; It causes cross thread issue
        });
    }
}
```

So far, I can believe is that it is due to updating UI from worker thread. Is there any work around to make it thread safe without changing in button click method i.e. probably making thread safe in viewmodel.

Comment: Update UI using Dispatcher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grab the UI's `SynchronizationContext` (using `SynchronizationContext.Current` from the UI thread when the app starts, for example), and store it in some static variable somewhere (i've called it `uiSynchronizationContext`).

Then on your `OnPropertyChanged` do something like:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
   uiSynchronizationContext.Post(
        o => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
       ,null
     );
}
```

Or you can use `Send` instead of `Post` if you want that operation synchronous (synchronous to the thread that started the send/post operation, it'll always be "synchronous" on the UI thread)

I particulary don't like doing direct databinding when multithreading (I prefer to poll with a timer on the UI thread from some graph object with the changes), but this should solve the problem.

I admiteddly haven't tested it

Comment: I am not sure, what do I need to pass in first parameter of Post method.

Comment: @akash88 the callback that the `SynchronizationContext` will execute (in your case, the calling of the `PropertyChanged` event... I've simplified it using `?.` from C# 6, but you can use the `handler` method as you where doing in your original question)

Comment: Sorry, the `SendOrPostCallback` delegate requires a parameter I had missed, I've updated the answer. This is a `state` object that you pass (it's the second parameter of the `Post` function). Since we are not using it, we can just disregard it on the delegate body, but we need to declare it on the lambda.

Comment: Wow !!! It works. Can you please explain a bit about synchronizationcontext role in above solution.

Comment: @akash88 you may check [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) if you want to know what the `SynchronizationContext` is all about. It explains it better than I could :-)

Comment: Thanks @Jcl . I'm accepting this answer as it solves my problem. If you got some time, can you please explain about your preferred approach i.e. "I prefer to poll with a timer on the UI thread from some graph object with the changes"?

Comment: @akash88 instead of using `DataBinding`, I store the changes to the viewmodel in a separate graph (I create that graph object subscribing to `PropertyChanged`)... the UI periodically (using a timer) reads that graph and updates the controls. I just don't make my viewmodels update the controls directly, and I use an intermediate object. That way I only need to lock on that intermediate object

Answer (score -1):

Did you try with CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls ? 

Like this :

```
private void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false; 
        _myViewModel.Name = "Updating from worker thread!"; It causes cross thread issue
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;

    });
}
```

I don't say that is the best way but it's working for me when I work with thread

EDIT :

```
private void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        _myViewModel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => _myViewModel.Name = "Updating from worker thread!"; ));
    });
}
```

Comment: I can make it thread safe in click event but I would like to make thread safe from viewmodel

Comment: @HenkHolterman : you're right... I edit my post with another method more safely

Comment: @C.Chagnon what makes you think a viewmodel has an `Invoke` method? why would it?